# Is it possible to bind Children in a StackPanel and preserve vertical SnapPoints?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer` and I would like to bind items and define their datatemplate so I use a `ItemsControl`. The problem appears to be the `ItemsControl` does not implement IScrollSnapPointsInfo and this is breaking my vertical snap points associated with the `StackPanel` children and the `ScrollViewer`.

These vertical snap points should allow the items bound to the stack panel to align in the vertical center position of the scroll viewer when the user scrolls.

Bellow is some sample code:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
               ZoomMode="Disabled"
               ZoomSnapPointsType="None"
               VerticalSnapPointsType="Mandatory"
               VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Center">
     <ScrollViewer.Content>
         <Grid>
             <!-- Start StackPanel -->
             <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" Margin="0,500,0,500" Orientation="Vertical">
                 <StackPanel.Children>
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}">
                         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ScrollItem">
                                 <Button Margin="8,0">
                                     <Button.Content>
                                         <Grid>
                                             <TextBlock Text="Hello" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" />
                                         </Grid>
                                     </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                           </DataTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel.Children>
       </StackPanel>
       <!-- End StackPanel -->
  </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer.Content>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Does anyone have experience with this? any advice on how I can restore the vertical snap points and still bind to the stack panel would be great.

Ideally I would like to just bind a list of items to the stack panel and define the template in xaml. This is much better than creating elements in code etc...

Comment: Why not using a ListView?

Comment: theres weaknesses to listview .. trying to emulate something done on another platform and listview won't work for me

Comment: I am not clear with your requirement, do you want to implement snap point using ItemsControl and display the ItemsControl's item in the outside scrollviewer's center?